# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'const' (T_CONST), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) on Phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, php-7.0

I am using phpmyadmin with `php7.0` but it give error like
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'const' (T_CONST), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /usr/share/php/PhpMyAdmin/MoTranslator/Translator.php on line 58`

its working fine with higher php version